# Lifetime of dependent classses in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, circular-dependency, object-lifetime

I have a class `A` that provides methods to construct instances of class `B`. And `B` holds a private reference to `A` and provides a constructor to set this reference.

```
class A { 
   public: 
     B* construct_B ();
}
class B {
  private:
    const A& private_A;
  public:
    B ( const A& my_A ): private_A (my_A) { }
}
```

The implementation of `construct_B` takes care of dynamic allocation and passing the reference to itself via `this`.

How do I implement this setup in such a way that I make sure that the lifetime of `A` is longer than `B` so that its reference remains valid? Notice that I don't care about all the possibilities of `construct_B` instead of returning a raw pointer I could return a smart pointer or similar.

One possible way of solving this could be having `B` instead of holding a reference to hold a smart pointer to `A`, and instead of dynamically allocating `B` in `construct_B` to take a static reference to `B` and then set it's pointer, something like

```
class A : 
   public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> { 
   public: 
      void setup_B ( const B& my_B ) { 
        my_B.set_A (shared_ptr_from_this() ) ;
}
class B {
  private:
    const shared_ptr<A> private_A_ptr;
  public:
    void set_A ( const shared_ptr<A> my_A ): 
        private_A_ptr (my_A) { }
}
```

which then could be implemented by
    int main () {
      A static_A;
      B static_B;
      A.setup_B (static_B);
    }

Does the `shared_ptr` of this last construction avoid the problem of `A` being deleted before `B`?

Comment: Why don't you try it out and make some console output? But here A will be deleted only when no-one points to A anymore.

Comment: "Does the shared_ptr of this last construction avoid the problem of A being deleted before B?' yes it does. The only caveat is that A itself must be owned by a shared_ptr otherwise shared_from_this() will be UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shared_ptr` is your answer. Something like this:

```
#include <memory>

struct A;

class B {
    const std::shared_ptr<A> private_A_ptr;
  public:
  B(std::shared_ptr<A> parent) : private_A_ptr(std::move(parent)) {}
};

struct A : 
std::enable_shared_from_this<A> 
{ 
  B make_b() {
    return B(shared_from_this());
  }
};

int main()
{
  // this would be invalid:  
  //A a;
  //auto b = a.make_b();

  // but this is fine

  auto pa = std::make_shared<A>();
  auto b = pa->make_b();

  // later...
  pa.reset();

  // A still exists because ownership was shared with b

}
```